Is there a Mitzvah to increase in the size of the Matzah and Maror?
The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 656:1) says that there is a Mitzvah to increase in the size of the Esrog more than the required Shiur, and the Magen Avraham there holds that this applies to all Mitzvah-articles as well, such as a Shofar and a Sefer Torah.
My question is: according to this, is there also a Mitzvah to increase in the size of the Matzah and Maror, or are they different, since the Mitzvah is performed by eating them, and once you start eating, the size begins to decrease?

Interesting question.  You should link and quote the magen avraham. He gives examples of shofar udekavatei,  meaning it a whole entity if bigger and smaller size, with the size making a qualitative difference.  But more matzah is just more matzah.
